# javascript validation telephone

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I have this function which objective is to validate a phone number introduced by a user with base in 2 regex variables.

if the user has the country Sweden selected and introduces 212341512 the warning shouldnt appear since the phone is valid however that doesnt happen. i still get the warning message to appear even if the phone number matches the conditions in the variable indicators.

```
function validateTelephone() {
            var telephone = document.getElementById('txtTel');
            var country=document.getElementById('ddCountry');
            var indicators= /^(21|22)\d{7}$/;

                   if (country.value == "Sweden") {
                        if (!indicators.test(telephone.value)) {
                        document.getElementById('lblWarning').style.color = "red";
                        document.getElementById('lblWarning').innerHTML = 'Invalid Telephone Number';
                        } else {
                        document.getElementById('lblWarning').innerHTML = '';
                        }
                    } else{
                     document.getElementById('lblWarning').innerHTML = ' ';
                    }

         }
```

if you guys have any suggestions about my code or a way to solve this problem i'd appreciate that since im new to this language

Answer (score 0):

I would use libphonenumber, which has a JavaScript library already made for you.

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

As for your code, the regex is correct, and does match the number provided.

Please try using Chrome's JavaScript debugger. (right-click page, inspect element, sources tab). Put in a breakpoint at the beginning of your function and see what happens. Check the values of variables.

Comment: thanks, what about the code? do you see anything wrong?

Comment: i can do that but if the country wasnt sweden the error would never get printed to begin with and all i get is the error

EDIT: guys i removed the "!" and inverted the IF statement and now it works. any ideas why it wasnt working?

Comment: I would upvote you, but your rep is beautiful 9,999, so I won't :D

Comment: So? Upvote you? Remember that since that moment your displayable reputation will be shortened and receive "k" at the end. Are you sure?

Comment: @nicael I get super-duper moderator powers if you do ;) So choose wisely

Comment: Done. Take your super powers :D